# If $A$ is open in a subspace $X$ of a metric space $Y$ and $X$ is open in $Y$, is $A$ open in $Y$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a subspace of a metric space $Y$. In general, if $A$ is open in $X$, then $A$ need not be open in $Y$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, an open disc on the $x$-$y$ plane is not open on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

But what if $X$ is an open subset of $Y$? Is $A$ necessarily open then? Intuitively I would say yes, but I can't prove it and can't find a counter example neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s true. Since $A$ is open in $X$, there is an open set $U$ in $Y$ such that $A=U\cap X$. If $X$ is also open in $Y$, then $U\cap X$ is the intersection of two open sets in $Y$ and is therefore also open in $Y$.